# When I create Eclipse projects, are the Java/Android dependencies copied again for each project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm just wondering this because in the near future I'll have to deal with a collaboration of different Android projects that will be sent to me. Will the default Android dependencies be copied again in every single file, or are they just referenced to save space?

If this isn't the case, how can I change it? I don't have the liberty of having a lot of space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the appcompat folders that are created with each project, then yes. They are re-created with each project. But if you delete the new one and reference the existing library, you shouldn't have a problem. I would back it up and try it before deleting.

Comment: Alright, and there's also a bunch of folders like "Android 4.4.2", "Android Private Libraries" and "Android Dependencies". Are all of these recreated with each project?

I understand each application will need the files, but it seems wasteful, considering Eclipse can easily make a dependency database or something.

Comment: The Android 4.4.2 is a reference to the SDK, so its not duplicated and doesn't take up any extra space. Android dependencies is just all your references, for example, the appcompat folders, which I already explained. Private libraries also shared, unless you add app specific libraries, such as Google Play Services